# Looking for a solution - Alert when Terminal Server licenses low

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

I've googled till my little google button fell off of my keyboard, here's what I'm looking for.  We need a solution that will shoot off an email when the number of terminal server licenses that we have falls below 90%.  Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a feeling you could set Nagios to do this kind of thing.  There's some code over on exchange.nagios.org under "check terminal services licensing".

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought to check there first.  P.S. it's exchange.nagios.org

Comment: Whatever system monitoring suite you've got, it should do this - if not it's not good enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this information is easily available in a way that would allow this to happen under windows 2003.

I know you that TS license information is available via WMI on Windows 2008, but that probably won't help.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2006/09/15/terminal-server-licensing-gateway-wmi-providers.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383802%28VS.85%29.aspx
- http://www.thincomputing.net/blog/terminal-server-licensing-gateway-wmi-providers.html